# UML диаграмма для шаблонных классов

Tags: шаблоны-с++, uml, диаграммы

Нужно сделать UML диаграмму классов. Проблема в том, что у меня есть 5 классов: Person, Meeting, Plan и ещё шаблоннный класс List, внутри которого есть шаблоннный класс node. Класс node принимает в себя классы person meeting.... Как это изобразить? И про связи между ними.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=uml+template+class&oq=uml+templ&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.9291j0j8&client=tablet-android-huawei&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=5SX2lDmQIuwJzM:

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что у меня будет шаблоный класс по середине и остальные будут связаны с ними как на данном примере?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете

Comment: А как насчёт того, что шаблонный класс в шаблонном классе

Comment: Да тоже самое, обернутое в тоже самое

Comment: Вот тут я был не прав. Шаблонный класс в шаблонном классе (то есть для объекта второго шаблонного класса), будет как два отдельных шаблонных класса, связанных композицией (или агрегацией), короче, связью с черным ромбиком (или белым). А вот если объявление одного в другом, то надо поэспериментировать, не пробовал